# How does windows controll display settings?

Tags: windows, display, display-driver, laptop-display

The reason I came up with this question is because the brightness controll of my laptop didn't work.

So my question is how does windows 10 change the brightness of the display? Does it just change the usual HDMI (or some simular) signal or is there a separate modul which is responsible for the brightness? And is the grafics driver or the monitor driver used for this?

I don't really get the whole process of changing the brightness to know were I should beginn to search for the problem...

Comment: The ability to change the brightness will only exist, if the display supports that functionality, and located in Action Center.  Why are you interested in knowing how Windows specifically recalls your brightness settings?

Comment: Any software control over the brightness is done via drivers: [Brightness Control in WDDM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn653987(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: @Ramhound there isn't a real reason. Just got curious while searching for my problem. If I got it right, the brightness isn't a change of the signal but a seperate option provided by the display.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Thanks for the link, will take a look at it.